# Finding the MX Record using C#?

Tags: c#, smtp, mx-record

How can I find the MX record for a mail server in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the answer of [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283103/finding-the-mx-record-using-c/4283140#4283140) and [RPK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283103/finding-the-mx-record-using-c/4283290#4283290) to get the MX record of a given domain.

But you'll need a DNS server to do the job. If you want to detect the DNS server of the machine where your code is executed, you can use the following.

```
NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in adapters)
{
    IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();

    if (properties.DnsAddresses.Count > 0)
        foreach (IPAddress ipAddress in properties.DnsAddresses)
             dnsServers.Add(ipAddress.ToString(), 53);
}
```

There is a [complete solution](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/52213#541648) (or at github [here](https://github.com/pmengal/MailSystem.NET)) that will do the whole job if you don't want to rewrite everything. Look for `GetMxRecords` static method.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this [DNS resolver project on codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/DNS_NET_Resolver.aspx). The library has a Resolver class that contains a method named Query which can be used to go after the MX record.

Answer (score 0):

[The NMail project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nmailserver/) contains a DNS client under trunk/NMail.DnsClient. The project is available under the Apache license.