# Get SMTP server via Email Domain

Tags: c#, email, smtp

ive got an email address lets say: xxx@hotmail.com
now i wanna get the smtp server where i can check the validation of this email address.
for checking the email address i need to connect to the smtp server so i can send an request and get the response.
ive got a lot of emailaddresses so its not possible to google every single dns server and add it to a list ...

Thats how i will check if the validation is correct:

```
startJob.Connect("THE SMTP SERVER IP I NEED", 25);
startJob.Authenticate("xx.xxx");
startJob.MailFrom(String.Format("ss.sss{0}@hotmail.com", this._emailExtension));
var response = startJob.RcptTo(item.EmailAddress);
startJob.Quit();
```

can someone help me maybe ? would be awesome
best regards,

Answer (score 1):

To find the SMTP servers, you need to query the MX records programmatically for each unique domain in your list of email addresses.

How to do this is addressed in this question: [Finding the MX Record using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283103/finding-the-mx-record-using-c)